# Replacement tap for Coleman 5 gal. water carrier

Tags: water

We have couple [Coleman 5 gal. water carriers](http://coleman.com/product/5-gallon-water-carrier/5620B718G). They are nice sturdy canisters, but they have major weak spot: their taps are of poor quality and easily broken — both ours are, and seems like a lot of people having same issue.

Coleman offers replacement part (cap assembly, Part# 5010001049), But there are issues with that. First of all, if they are so shoddy, why get same thing that only going to break in few uses. Secondly — the price: replacement part itself is about $3, plus shipping and handling would add another $5 making the total about the same as we had got the whole thing for (bought on sale). Thirdly, it is “temporarily unavailable”, and no telling when it shall become, indeed, available.

Is there other places that would have replacement available at better price? Is there aftermarket replacement that is of better quality and reasonably priced? If not a functional tap, is there some sort of standard “non-interactive” cap that could be used as replacement?

**Edit.** Open mouth dimensions: 1 and 7/8" in diameter, 3/4" out from the surface of the canister, 1/8" thread pitch.

Comment: In the page you linked to it looks like coleman are saying call their customer service department and they'll see what they can do - they may of course just tell you to buy the replacement part but it could be worth a try if they give you a couple of replacements for free? Not unheard of.

Comment: What's the diameter on the open mouth?

Comment: @Masked, what should I measure? Inside opening, outside (including thickness of material), outside of a thread?

Answer (score 5):

Here's my quickie hack for temporary replacement.
Found similar size water bottle pop top and screwed it on.
Slight slow leak so stand upright when not in use.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if they carry the diameter you are looking for but when a spigot breaks on one of my canisters I usually go to [Ace Hardware](http://www.acehardwareoutlet.com/productdetails.aspx?sku=998954526) and pickup a replacement. I have had good luck with Rubbermaid ones. I would expect stores like Home Depot or Lowes to have them as well.

The [Reliance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GKIN0S) ones work if the mouth is the same size, I like them because you can turn the spigot inside when transporting or not in use.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to the question, but something to consider. Reliance cans may be a better purchase, because their taps, while not immune from damage, are easier to repair and improve. This is what we did with ours — short nipple and a quality brass ball valve:

[image: Reliance tap repaired]

Not sure what thread is that (iron pipe or hose thread), but we just had some 3/4" nipple lying around and it worked. It’s bulkier, but quite a bit sturdier, and the cap itself is solid enough.

As for Coleman, the workaround my father uses is to buy a new one, then return it with a broken tap. He’s unapologetic, saying maybe that’ll teach them to improve their product. Which does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Found this on an amazon review:
"I bought a flat, low-profile cap for an interim solution as well as to have a more durable closure for storage and transportation. A cap which fits perfectly is the wide-mouth cap for the smaller (16oz) sized Nalgene bottle. This is not the commonly found wide-mouth size, and it's not a narrow-mouth cap. The complete 16oz bottle costs around $9, but I was able to buy a replacement lid from REI for about $3. The blue color that it came in is a nice match for the Coleman blue. (See pic.)"
[Full link](http://www.amazon.com/review/RLJ1CDEDXD5AO/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00168PI4S&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=3375251&store=sporting-goods)

[for sale at Amazon](http:///) (you want the 53 mm replacement cap)

Answer (score 3):

I have been in contact with Coleman via email for the past several months. They now have a replacement spigot in stock (Jan 2018), with a different part number. The new part number is 3000005305. I *really hope* this means the design and/or materials have been improved so it doesn't break after the first use.

I just ordered two of them, and they should arrive within 6-10 business days.

This isn't available yet on their website, you have to call Coleman to place an order. Their number is 1-800-835-3278.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the Coleman 5 gallon water jug spigot because my household has two Reliance water jugs with cheap nylon spigots. Went to local Menards Store because they had it in stock and purchased a hose bibb described as Homewerks 3/4" MIP x 3/4" FIP Lead Free Brass Hose Bibb. Best feature besides the fact that the tapered threads fit the Reliance (and I suspect also the Coleman) is the ball valve that a one-quarter turn between fully off to fully on. Here's the link to the one I bought:

https://www.menards.com/main/plumbing/valves/hose-bibbs-wall-faucets-wall-hydrants/homewerks-3-4-mip-x-3-4-fip-lead-free-brass-hose-bibb/133-2-34-12/p-1501569235536-c-19519.htm?tid=4686131630615272698&ipos=7

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I went to ACE Hardware and built my own for the Orange 5 Gallon water containers as well. Cost 11.29 for (1) spigot, (1) nipple, (2) gaskets and a (1) stainless washer to compress the washer on the outside. Yes the cost is a bit more than a factory replacement, but now I have a real faucet which doesn't spill, and can be put on the edge of a counter and used without a spill control device (aka an used milk jug) to catch drips and spill during use. Yes it is a bit more obtrusive, but we use in it our cabin, and if necessary, the spigot aparatus can be removed and reinstalled quickly.